# How can I detect black frames in Opencv with Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have got a project about data from broadcasting.I wrote split from video to frame for python. But I just figure out it would be better if I can take video's frame only between blackFrames.Is it possible? I share my code;

```
import cv2
import time
import os

def video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc):
"""Function to extract frames from input video file
and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
Args:
    input_loc: Input video file.
    output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
Returns:
    None
"""
try:
    os.mkdir(output_loc)
except OSError:
    pass
# Log the time
time_start = time.time()
# Start capturing the feed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)
# Find the number of frames
video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
print ("Number of frames: ", video_length)
count = 0
print ("Converting video..\n")
# Start converting the video
while cap.isOpened():
    # Extract the frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Write the results back to output location.
    cv2.imwrite(output_loc + "/%#05d.jpg" % (count+1), frame)
    count = count + 1
    # If there are no more frames left
    if (count > (video_length-1)):
        # Log the time again
        time_end = time.time()
        # Release the feed
        cap.release()
        # Print stats
        print ("Done extracting frames.\n%d frames extracted" % count)
        print ("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
        break

input_loc = 'try.mp4'
output_loc = 'try/'
video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since images in openCV (or in your case frames) are represented as a numpy array, they can be averaged for low values (which represent black frames).

```py
import numpy as np

# converts the frame to gray scale for easier computation
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

if np.average(gray) < 20:
    # skips an iteration, so the frame isn't saved
    continue
```

In this case `20` is a threshold used for "black images". If you have some that are lighter, you can increase this constant. Therefore, your total code should look somewhat like this:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import os


def video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc):
"""Function to extract frames from input video file
and save them as separate frames in an output directory.
Args:
    input_loc: Input video file.
    output_loc: Output directory to save the frames.
Returns:
    None
"""
try:
    os.mkdir(output_loc)
except OSError:
    pass


# Log the time
time_start = time.time()
# Start capturing the feed
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_loc)

# Find the number of frames
video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
print("Number of frames: ", video_length)
count = 0

print("Converting video..\n")
# Start converting the video
while cap.isOpened():
    # Extract the frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if np.average(gray) < 20:
        # skips an iteration, so the frame isn't saved
        continue

    # Write the results back to output location.
    cv2.imwrite(output_loc + "/%#05d.jpg" % (count+1), frame)
    count = count + 1

    # If there are no more frames left
    if count > video_length-1:
        # Log the time again
        time_end = time.time()
        # Release the feed
        cap.release()
        # Print stats
        print("Done extracting frames.\n%d frames extracted" % count)
        print("It took %d seconds forconversion." % (time_end-time_start))
        break

input_loc = 'try.mp4'
output_loc = 'try/'
video_to_frames(input_loc, output_loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had some frames with majority black but not completely black. These were still marked as black frames by `np.average(image) < 20`. Instead, I used `np.max(image) < 20` which worked out pretty well in my case. As Komron said, the 20 might need to be adjusted for your usecase.